# Why is MVC actionlink not rendering correctly?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.actionlink

I am passing this :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditCRMRequest", "CRM", new { Id = item.Id })%>
```

and I am getting in browser :

```
http://something.com/CRM/EditCRMRequest?Length=3
```

with Error Code :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditCRMRequest(Int32)' in
>   'ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers.CRM.CRMController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

If I explicitly write this in browser it works fine:

```
http://something.com/CRM/EditCRMRequest?Id=3
```

Comment: Like the answer below mentioned, if you look at the method overload that you are using it is expecting htmlAttributes and not routeValues. That is why you get the ?length=3 on your query string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct way:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditCRMRequest", "CRM", new { Id = item.Id },null)%>
```

No overload method like this:

```
Html.ActionLink(string text, string action, string controller, object routeValues)
```

If you write like above, `Lenght=3` is represent "CRM". Controller name behave as routeValues

Correct method is:

```
Html.ActionLink(string text, string action, string controller, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```