# @Html.ActionLink how to add a query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to setup a query string in a View using MVC and Razor.

Here my code

```
Controller: Home
ActionResult: Daily
QueryString: DateForLookUp 

@Html.ActionLink("Next Day", "Daily", "Home", new { @DateForLookUp = @Model.AddOneDay() })
```

the result at the moment is

```
http://mysite.com/Home/Daily?lenght=4
```

it should be

```
http://mysite.com/Home/Daily?DateForLookUp=01/01/2014
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: same like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687638/why-is-mvc-actionlink-not-rendering-correctly/14687749#14687749

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Html.ActionLink` has a lots of [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

And you are using the [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which interprets your controller name `"Home"` as the route values.

One of correct [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)/sysntax is:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Next Day", //linkText
    "Daily", //actionName
    "Home", //controllerName
     new { @DateForLookUp = @Model.AddOneDay() }, //routeValues
     null //htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: this solved the problem @Html.ActionLink("Next Day", "Daily", new { @DateForLookUp = @Model.AddOneDay() })

Comment: @GibboK yeah, if don't need the specify the controller then that overload also can work.